# How to access Linux startup tty

Tags: linux, kernel, arch-linux, tty

I have a problem that is shown at the end of bootstrapping the kernel, just before the screen is cleared and Linux swaps me to tty1 where I can put my login.

How can I access the *bootstrapping* tty after init? (More specifically, in Archlinux)

And I know it's not the same tty because if I press Shift+RePag I don't go beyond my current tty

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's still the same `tty1`, it just gets cleared (including scrollback).

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Disable_Clearing_of_Boot_Messages

If you are able to log in:

```
dmesg | less
```

has the kernel logs.

Maybe look at /var/log/everything

Comment: I'd vote you, but I don't have enough reputation at superuser.com

Comment: I think that was my first answer!

Comment: @ssice Should have linked your profile with the others you have at SE. You get +100.

Comment: @Trinidad how can I link my profile?

Comment: @ssice http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79362/are-stack-exchange-accounts-automatically-linked

Comment: @Trinidad I saw that before I commented. But, if it is automatic, then how could I get +100?

Comment: @ssice You get +100 if you have 200 or more in any of the other sites IIRC

Comment: Then IDK why I don't: I have 256 (0x100) points in SO

Comment: I do have now more than 300 points, maybe it was that : )

Answer (score 1):

You could use the kernel command line option boot_delay=100 to slow down the screen output sufficiently to see what is going on.  Useful when things scroll off the screen too fast to read during booting.